# How to make all groups one-to-one relationships in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, replace, unique

There are two columns in pandas dataframe.
I need to check if all the pairs are one-to-one relationships, and if a column is not one-to-one then replace it with the value that appears most often.

For example, if column A has the value of 12 and 25 in column B, then all the 12s in column A must have 25 for column B.

I was able to count the unique value after groupby to check which column has one-to-many relationship but got stuck here.

```
articles.groupby(['A'],)['B'].nunique()
```

Here is the dummy data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
                 , 'B':[4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,7]})
```

In this case, 3 in column A has one-to-many (3-6, 3-7).
Because there are 2 pairs with 6 and only one pair with 7, 7 should be replaced with 6.

Comment: What if multiple As are paired with a single B? For example, what's the outcome for `{'A': [1,1,1,2,2], 'B':[1,2,2,1,1]}`?

Comment: Thank you for the question! Let's just assume that there is no such instance.